# DataGrid inside TabItem event handling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tabitem, routed-events, mahapps.metro

I have a TabControl with two TabItems, inside the one TabItem I have a DataGrid.
I'm trying to handle the TabItem click, and it works, but, when I click in one row of the "dataGrid1" the event  "TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp" of TabItem click is fired too. See the code:

```
<TabControl Height="211" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,29,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="417" >
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem MouseLeftButtonUp="TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="134" Name="dataGrid1" Width="307" />
        </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Note: I can't use the personalize `<TabItem.Header>` because I'm using MahApps, if I use TabItem.Header the style os TabItem will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MouseLeftButtonUp` event is bubbling routed event. When you on the `DataGrid`s row the event bubbling through its ancestors and calls the corresponding handlers, **TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp** for `TabItem` in your case.

In your **TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp** event you can check who raised the event, which control is the origin. If its not the `TabItem` do nothing.

```
private void TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     if(sender is TabItem)
     {
           //do the work
     }
}
```

Comment: When a click on the TabItem the OriginalSource is a Border, and when i click right on the text of the TabItem the OriginalSource is a TextBlock, so, this solution dont work.

Comment: I do some modifications in your solution the sender.GetType() will return the type os the control (DataGrid or TabItem), so, your solution works, i will mark it as answer, can you edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You will recieve the EventArgs with MouseLeftButtonUp event. Just filter out whatever you need.